# Объявление и инициализация переменной вне функции в golang

Tags: golang

Почему вне тела функции нельзя объявить переменную, а потом присвоить ей значение, но сделать это в одну строчку - можно? Например, код :

```
func main() {
   vr()
}

//  Вне функций:
    var vr1 bool                // объявление
//  vr1 = true                  // так нельзя (вне функции), почему?
    var vr2 bool = true         // так можно
    var vr4 bool


func vr(){

   fmt.Println(" vr1 = ", vr1)  // false
   fmt.Println(" vr2 = ", vr2)  // true
   //---
   var vr3 bool
   vr3 = true                   // а так можно (внутри функции)
   fmt.Println(" vr3 = ", vr3)  // true
   //----
   vr4 = true
   fmt.Println(" vr4 = ", vr4)  // true
}
```

Comment: Вне тела функции могут существовать только декларации (declarations)[https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope] которые вы можете опционально инициализировать выражениями (expressions)[https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions]. В теле функции вы указываете строгую *последовательность* инструкций (statements) и (declarations). `vr1 = true` это - (Assignment Statement)[https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignment]

Comment: @biosckon ,  спасибо, - буду читать и вникать ... думал есть простое правило, по которому выделяется память в обоих случаях (внутри ф-ции и вне) ; а понимая - легче запомнить.